# install Rpy2 on Mac got error

Tags: python, r, macos

I am trying to install Rpy2 on mac Yosemite. I have read all the posts given by different people about how to install this package. None was useful for me since my problem is specific

I first did

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

Then I did

```
pip install rpy2
```

But I got something like

```
Collecting rpy2
  Downloading rpy2-2.5.6.tar.gz (165kB)
    100% |################################| 167kB 2.4MB/s 
    R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) -- "Pumpkin Helmet"
    /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R CMD config --ldflags
    /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R CMD config --cppflags
        Compilation parameters for rpy2's C components:
            include_dirs    = ['/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include']
            library_dirs    = []
            libraries       = ['lzma', 'z', 'icucore', 'm', 'iconv']
            extra_link_args = ['-F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/..', '-framework', 'R']
    R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) -- "Pumpkin Helmet"
Collecting singledispatch (from rpy2)
  Downloading singledispatch-3.4.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from singledispatch->rpy2)
Installing collected packages: singledispatch, rpy2

  Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 232, in main
      status = self.run(options, args)
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 347, in run
      root=options.root_path,
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 549, in install
      **kwargs
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in install
      self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 963, in move_wheel_files
      isolated=self.isolated,
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 234, in move_wheel_files
      clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 212, in clobber
      shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
    File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
      with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
  IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/singledispatch.py'
```

I tried to run it with

```
easy_install rpy2
```

Then I got some errors

```
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-1490.pth'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

  https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
```

Finlly I did it in another way and it worked apparently

```
sudo easy_install rpy2
```

Comment: you need to change to the superuser to run this command, try run "sudo -s", then run the command again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check packages installed use:

1 - in a Python shell/prompt the command `help('modules')`

2 - The command `pip list`

Output will be similar to:

> bottle (0.12.7) cffi (0.8.6) characteristic (14.1.0) cryptography
>   (0.6) cssselect (0.9.1) django-mongodb-engine (0.5.2) djangotoolbox
>   (1.6.2) folium (0.1.2) google-api-python-client (1.3.1) httplib2 (0.9)
>   lxml (3.4.0) oauth2client (1.3.2) Pattern (2.6) Pillow (2.6.0) pip
>   (1.5.6) pyasn1 (0.1.7) pyasn1-modules (0.0.5) pycparser (2.10) pymongo
>   (2.7.2) pyOpenSSL (0.14) queuelib (1.2.2) requests (2.4.3) rsa (3.1.4)
>   Scrapy (0.24.4) scrapyd (1.0.1) selenium (2.44.0) service-identity
>   (14.0.0) setuptools (3.6) simplejson (3.6.5) six (1.8.0) Twisted
>   (14.0.2) uritemplate (0.6) w3lib (1.10.0) wsgiref (0.1.2)
>   zope.interface (4.1.1)

Comment: My output is not like yours, it is something like below >>> help ('modules')

Please wait a moment while I gather a list of all available modules...

AVFoundation        _Snd                dircache            pwd
Accounts            _TE                 dis                 py2app
AddressBook         _Win                distutils           py_compile

Comment: I pasted the output from pip. the one from help modules is much bigger and not easy to paste here